# CSS background image not working/ visible

Tags: css, background-image

I have some problems with my css background-image property. According to the syntax i saw when studying my syntax would be true. I checked and the image is in the right folder. 
Here is my code

HTML:

```
<div class="left"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.left {
    width:240px;
    background-image: url(img/sos-logo.png);
}
```

Why is it not working? Help please.

Comment: Your div does not have any content and has no height so it does not show see http://jsfiddle.net/yjxfz0nq/1/

Comment: Unless you set the height as well as width.

Comment: If you've already set a height and it's not working, check to see if you misspelled anything on the background image line.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a height attribute to the div to get it to show up. By default, an empty `<div>` is has a height of 0px.

see pen http://codepen.io/JustH/pen/EavXZO